# What is the relevance of young animals in AC3

Tags: assassins-creed-3

On occasion, I see bear cubs and fawn.

- Do they have a purpose other than adding additional realism to the game?
- Can they be hunted?

  - Are they worth more or less than adults?

Comment: Stand up against malicious pointless downvoting. Comment people, or dont bother pressing the arrow.

Comment: @Ender - Thanks for that! So frustrating. Don't like the question, say why and I'll fix it!

Comment: Removed the platform tag, as I think it's totally irrelevant here.

Comment: I must say, I've never seen any young animals in AC3 myself. I can't say I'll play it again soon, but when I do I'll keep a better eye out for that.

Comment: @Ender That is precisely the opposite of how it's supposed to work. Commenting is courtesy, downvoting is public duty. That said, in this case... random downvotes happen; don't sweat them.

Comment: @badp I think we will have to agree to disagree about this method, and Im probably gonna open a meta about it as soon as my PCS is over. Downvoting without commenting about why you think the question is bad is malicious and does NOTHING as far as I'm concerned except cause bad feelings, when it could be used to teach better habits.

Comment: @Ender I agree there's not enough space in this margin to discuss this in depth; flem probably isn't _that_ interested. I'll see you on Meta.

Comment: @badp. I actually am interested. I've had this same discussion on multiple SE sites, each with a different outcome. Seems different communities have different rules.

Comment: @flem Here you go. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/please-dont-misuse-the-voting-system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Young animals can't be hunted. They are only a sign that larger game is nearby. This means that you can shoot at the baby animals and they will take no damage and will not die. Larger game is show with a white outline surrounding the animal. When you get to a baby that outline is not shown and thus you will not be able to use any attacks on it. There is a video below that shows the outline and the babies without one.

Comment: Are you sure of this or just guessing? I tried (about an hour ago) to hunt fawn but was unable to target them. I've had similar defeat with bear cubs...

Comment: No I'm sure I'm right.

Comment: @flem if this is the answer your looking for please accept it or tell me how I can improve it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't agree. After many attempts, I've not been able to kill the young animals. Can you reference something as evidence to your answer?

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: You didn't kill the animals. I wouldn't consider running around after the animals a successful hunt...

Comment: I notice you've updated your answer from "can" to "can't" be hunted. Marking as correct for that edit and the evidential video.